# At or in? What's the difference? Which is more preferable?

Tags: prepositions

Which one is correct and what's the difference?

What would you say if someone asked you what you were doing yesterday:

> I was shopping **at** a convenience store yesterday.
>
> I was shopping **in** a convenience store yesterday.
>
> I was doing the shopping **at** a convenience store yesterday.
>
> I was doing the shopping **in** a convenience store yesterday.

or what you did yesterday:

> I did the shopping **at** a convenience store yesterday.
>
> I did the shopping **in** a convenience store yesterday.

Comment: Both are OK.  There may be a slight difference in meaning.

Comment: The denotations are the same, but 'I was shopping at a convenience store yesterday.' does not conjure up a picture of the location the way 'I was shopping in a convenience store yesterday.' might. The first is the unmarked, clinical version.

Comment: The OP's previous question, [At a shop or in a shop?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/296174/at-a-shop-or-in-a-shop). Any reason to ask the same question?